# How do I get Hexchat to start with and show a system tray icon on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: system-tray, hexchat

How do I get Hexchat to show a system tray icon on Ubuntu 18.04? I have tried to launch with 'hexchat --minimize=2', and tried to find a way to enable the system tray in Settings -> Preferences -> Alerts where the option should be available.It is not. What am I missing? All other chat clients I use (Skype, Signal and Slack) have working system tray icons.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this gnome extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/
It is working for me on Ubuntu 18.04